# C# passing jagged array in class constructor

Tags: c#

I have a jagged array that I pass to object constructor but whenever I edit the array that I passed as parameter, the array inside the instance of the object also gets edited for some reason.

```
bool[][] clickedArray = new bool[7][];
clickedArray[0] = new bool[3];
clickedArray[1] = new bool[3];
clickedArray[2] = new bool[3];
clickedArray[3] = new bool[2];
clickedArray[4] = new bool[3];
clickedArray[5] = new bool[3];
clickedArray[6] = new bool[4];
```

I read some ints from a file and set the bools to true or false depending on the ints. By default, all elements of the jagged array are set to false:

```
for (int i = 0; i < clickedArray.Length; i++) // i < 7
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < clickedArray[i].Length; j++) 
            {
                clickedArray[i][j] = false;
            }
        }
```

I also have a List of objects. I call the constructor by adding new instance of the object to the list: `buildsList.Add(new Builds(tokens[0], clickedArray));`

Here is the constructor:

```
public Builds(string buildName, bool[][] jagged)
    {
        this.buildName = buildName;
        jaggedArray = jagged;
    }
```

I don't know why but when I, for example, reset the array and then call a function such as:

```
int selection = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
clickedArray = buildsList[selection].getJaggedArray();
```

it turns out that the jagged array from the object inside the list also had it's values reset.

Comment: `jaggedArray = jagged;` => `jaggedArray = Array.ConvertAll(jagged, b => [bool[]]b.Clone());`

Comment: Pass by Reference issue

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in .NET are object on the heap, so you have a reference. That reference is passed by value, meaning that changes to the contents of the array are reflected anywhere.

So:   `jaggedArray = jagged;`

they have the same reference pointer to the same address in the memory.

Use `Array.Copy` method to avoid that issue in order to copy elements fr
om the source array to the destination. Check how to use [Array.Copy Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4yx47a1(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Array.Copy(jagged, jaggedArray, 7); inside the constructor does not fix the problem. Am I doing it wrong?